# Remote access server (xamp) using http

Tags: php, html, url, ip, remote-access

I have remote access to another computer, and I can access that computer using its ip address and xamp server is also installed on that remote machine.

Now what I want is to access the file placed in that wamp server such as .php file from my own computer, such as using `http://something/file.php`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ip of the remote machine plus the folder of the project which is located under htdocs folders on xampp.

For example,

```
192.168.1.1/folderName
```

I'm not sure that is going to help you but why no try!